# php - how to redirect if parent

Tags: php, parent

There is an iframe on my index page that is not suposed to be viewed outside of that parent page.

So if the iframe isnt being viewed on the parent page http://mysite.com/index.php it should be redirected to http://mysite.com/

Im thinking of something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== 'http://mysite.com/') {
    include_once 'http://mysite.com/';
}
```

Comment: Doing this in an airtight manner is flat out impossible. Why bother trying to make it harder? It reminds me of "clever" JS that disallows opening the browser's context menu.

Comment: That not possible with php, use javascript to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it similarly to your approach:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] !== 'mysite.com') {
   header("Location: mysite.com");
}
```

if you need it for just your index page then

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] !== 'mysite.com' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!=='index.php') {
   header("Location: mysite.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `header( "Location: http://..." )`

Comment: That nails the redirect, but if you read the question you will find that the if condition is itself wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Php has no way of detecting whether the page was requested from a frame .. at least not one that's consistent enough to mention.  If you want some javascript, you can use:

```
if (top != self) {
    // you're in an iframe, or similar.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
top.location.href
```

But that will only work if both pages (the iframe and the main page) are being served from the same domain.

```
if(top.location.href!=="pageyouexpect")
{
REDIRECT WHERE YOU WANT
}
```